# Symfony2 - how should I implement validation on my non-doctrine objects?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Doctrine entities have validation metadata specified on their member fields independently of forms. Symfony2's form system somehow uses the validators provided by the entity.

**How does that work? What ties it all together?**

I have a non-doctrine model which I would like to validate *without forms*, but when I use forms they should use that validation information and display it correctly. So I need to:

- Define validators on a **non-doctrine object**
- Define validators **without annotations**
- Allow the model to validate itself **without a form**
- **Allow forms to use the validators** on the non-doctrine object

Comment: Start by working your way through here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html.  The is nothing special about doctrine entity objects.  They are just plain old php objects so everything should work just fine on your objects.  The validator service will allow validating your objects outside of a form.  You can also dig into the validation component documentation.

Comment: And to answer your first question: S2 uses the Resources/config/validation.yml file to tie things together by default.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it handles your situation (as no code for a non-doctrine entity is provided), but you can use symfony validation constraints on values and arrays of values:

[Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays)

As an example of validating a couple of date values in array:

```
private function isInvalid($data)
{
    $response = array();
    $constraint = new Collection(array(
                'from'=>new Date(),
                'to'=>new Date(),
            ));

    $validationList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($data, $constraint);

    if(count($validationList)>0) {
        foreach($validationList as $err) { 
            array_push($data,array(
                'field'=>$err->getPropertyPath(),
                'message'=>$err->getMessage(),
            ));
        }
        return $response;
    }
    return false;
}
```